# Почему не хочет сокращать строку?

Tags: python

У меня есть строка, которую я хотел сократить, но также после неё поставить цифру, которая укажет сколько раз повторялись буквы подряд, но постоянно выводится **[None, 0, 0, 0]**. Что не так с этим скриптом???

```
import os; os.system('cls')

s = str(input('Введите строку\n> '))
r = [None]
c = 0

for i in s:
    if i != r[-1] and c != 0:
        r.append(i)
        с += 1
    elif i != r[-1] and c == 0:
        r.append(c)

print(r)
```

Пока оно должно выводить все элементы массива **r**, которую если сложить получится сокращенная строка.

Comment: Извините, поменял код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, похоже, сами себя запутали. На самом деле, пока буква одна и та же, надо тоько увеличивать счетчик, а все остальное делать при ее смене

```
s = str(input('Введите строку\n> '))
# добавляем первую букву
r = [s[0]]
c = 1

for i in s[1:]:
    # буква сменилась, записываем счетчик предыдущей и ее саму
    if i != r[-1] :
        r.extend([c, i])
        c = 1
    # та же буква, увеличиваем счетчик
    else :
        c += 1
# надо добавить счетчик последней буквы
r.append(c)
print(r) 

ababbabbb
['a', 1, 'b', 1, 'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'a', 1, 'b', 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание, что в своем коде вы установили значение `c = 0`, но меняете это значение только при условии, что `c != 0`.

Так и выходит, что в блок `if` ваша программа никогда не зайдет, `c` всегда равна `0`, а на вывод будет идти `[None, 0, 0, ...]` с количеством нулей, равным длине вашей строки.